# Proper way to inject javascript code?

Tags: javascript, web, proxy

I would like to create a site with a similar functionality like [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com) or [hypothes.is](http://hypothes.is) has: users can enter any address and the site opening with an additional menu. I gues this is done with some middleware-proxy solution and a javascript is injected in the response, but I'm not sure. Do you have any idea how to implement the same feature? How can it work with secured (https) sites?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The entire site is fetched by the server, the source code is parsed, code injected and then sent back to the requesting client.

It works with SSL just fine, because it's two separate requests - the request that gets sent to the endpoint is not seen by the user.

The certificate is valid because it's being served under google's domain.

In order to actually implement something like this could potentially be quite complicated, because:

- The HTML you are parsing won't necessarily conform to your expectations, or even be valid
- The content you're forwarding to the client will likely reference resources with a relative URI. This means that you also need to intercept these requests and pull the resources (images, external css, js, etc) and serve them back to the client - and also rewrite the URLs.
- It's very easy to break content by injecting arbitrary javascript. You need to be careful that your injected code is contained and won't interfere with any existing code on the site.
- It's very common for an implementation such as this to have non-obvious security concerns, often resulting in XSS attacks being possible.